# Scale an arrays dimensions in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am wanting to make a method that can take in an array of n dimensions and then do some sorting with that info. The sorting part is out of the scope of this question though since the part I am stuck on is making a method accept an array of n dimensions. Normally you include something like int[] nums as a parameter. However, this does not allow for a scalable dimensional input. I did some research and the following code accurately calculates the dimensions of an array but I am not sure where to go from there since I cant figure out how to initialize an array of n dimensions from just an Object.

```
public static int dimensionOf(Object arr) {
    int dimensionCount = 0;
    Class<?> c = arr.getClass(); // getting the runtime class of an object

    while (c.isArray()) { // check whether the object is an array
        c = c.getComponentType(); // returns the class denoting the component type of the array
        dimensionCount++;
    }
    return dimensionCount;
}
```

Here is something else to explain my issue lets say someone passes in a 2 dimensional array as the object. If that happened my dimensions variable would be equal to 2 since its using the above code to determine the dimension of the array. The thing I am stuck on is figuring out how to then produce a useable variable. Here you can see I tried to cast the object (which I know is an instance of array) to a 1d array which would through an error since the incoming object is a 2d array.

```
public static int sortNDimensionalArray(Object obj) {
    int dimensions = dimensionOf(obj);

    //This means we did not get an array passed in
    if(dimensions == 0) return -1;

    int[] array = (int[]) obj;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your question is **very** confusing; were you aware that Java supports jagged arrays? `int[][] arr = { { 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };`

Comment: Yes I know that... I am wanting to make my method accept an array of any dimensions which means int[], int[][], int[][][], etc. Because I need to accept any array I need to use an object as my methods parameter. So lets say someone passes in your 2d array all my method will see is an object then using the code I posted above I will know its 2d. Based on that info how can I reconstruct the original array that was passed in?

Comment: You can't. Without also passing a `Class<?>` that corresponds to the array type.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it out and got this and it works for me:

```
public static int dimensionOf(Object... args) {
    int dim = 0;
    Class<?> c = args.getClass();
    while(c.isArray()) {
        c = c.getComponentType();
        dim++;
    }
    return dim;
}
```

Comment: but! this would return 1 if you do smth like this `dimensionOf(1)`, cause it passes Object[]